# iOS border in UIProgressView

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

is there any way to add border around UIProgressView in iOS7? I dont find any property in storyboard. I've try do it like that also:

```
progressView.layer.borderWidth = 0.07;
```

but it gives me only border on top and bottom of progressView but not on the sides.

Comment: create a custom progressView with custom background image

Comment: Consider using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding your progress view as the subview of another view, where the container view has a border, or a background colour as required.